# How to convert inputsource to inputstream which will feed to stringreader as the parameter?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, inputstream

I have requirement, where i need to get the xml from the server to parse if it is present and if not take the file from assets folder.

What ever the xml i'm getting using inputstream im passing it as the parameter for StringReader for further processing. I'm using XmlPullParser for parsing.

But i'm not able to pass the inputsource paramter to stringreader for further parsing. I don't to use document reader. Please find the code as below.

```
 private void  readSynconfiguration( )
    {

        XmlParser xmlparser = new XmlParser();

            try {
                String strFromMbo = getDataFromMBO();
                if(strFromMbo != null && !strFromMbo.isEmpty()) {   // first
                    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(strFromMbo));
                   // result = getStringFromInputStream(is);
                }
                else {
                    context = RetailExecutionApplication.getApp().getApplicationContext();
                    InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("syncSettings.xml");
                    result = getStringFromInputStream(stream);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                syncSetting = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        StringReader labelReader = new StringReader(result);

        try {
            if(syncSetting) {
                labelSharedInstance.clear();
                labelSyncDetails = xmlparser.LabelsParse(labelReader);
                labelSharedInstance = labelSyncDetails;
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            syncSetting = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can not pass inputsorce object directly to StringReader. First of all you convert inputsorce to reader as follows :

Reader reader = yourInputSource.getCharacterStream();
String result = reader.toString();
```

StringReader labelReader = new StringReader(result);

Comment: Thanks USKMobility. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Hello USKMobility, when i modify the code as you mentioned above, the entire xml is not storing in result string. It is storing something like JavaStringIO etc to result variable

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing things. The [XmlPullParser.setInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#setInput%28java.io.Reader%29) method takes `Reader`, so that's what you need to provide.

In case 1 (from database), you have a String in `strFromMbo`, so just wrap with a `StringReader`.

In case 2 (from file), you have two choices:

- Load entire file into memory as a String. This is what you're doing.
- Use a `FileReader`. Uses less memory.

In both cases, remember to close your resources.

I don't understand what "inputsource" has to do with anything.

```
String xml = getDataFromMBO();
if (xml == null || xml.isEmpty()) {
    context = RetailExecutionApplication.getApp().getApplicationContext();
    try (InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("syncSettings.xml")) {
        xml = getStringFromInputStream(stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        syncSetting = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

if (syncSetting) {
    try {
        labelSharedInstance.clear();
        labelSyncDetails = new XmlParser().LabelsParse(new StringReader(xml));
        labelSharedInstance = labelSyncDetails;
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        syncSetting = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Andreas, I will getting from assets only if i cannot get it from db. That is why im using input source

Comment: Hello Andreas, when i try to do changes as you suggested, it is giving an exception. Is this expection is ocurring because of the spaces or next line in the xml file?

Comment: That depends on the parsing implementation and the exception, neither of which you have shared. If you can't figure it out, I'd suggest creating a new question with the relevant information, following this guideline: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Andreas, exception and logic was in another laptop. It got crashed. Soon i provide those details, please help me with this regards

Comment: the exception was----> Unexpected token (position:TEXT\n\n@20:1 in java.io.StringReader@3c88a151)

Comment: As I said, post a new question, showing the relevant pieces. That would be the XML, the parsing code, and the exception. In as minimal a form as possible to reproduce the problem. See the link I gave.